# How to remove LibreOffice's File Explorer context menu options in Windows?

Tags: libreoffice

I have LibreOffice installed but it put a whole bunch of options in my 'New' context menu in File Explorer (Windows 10). I want it gone but I can't find the option in LibreOffice's preferences. I found some answers on the web saying "open regedit and modify the registry" but that's ridiculous - I'm looking for the option provided by LibreOffice settings - I mean it MUST exist somewhere, right?

If the option doesn't exist I'd also like to know, I'll then create a feature request. And uninstall LO until they fix it because it's driving me nuts :P

Answer (score 3):

So I haven't found the option yet but you can disable it during installation. When asked, choose Custom and disable the Windows Explorer integration.

Still curious where the option is to disable it after installation though..